# Shorten content of an element using CSS

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page which introduce latest blog posts with a read more link which is generated dynamically.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
      <article>
        <div class="date">
          <span class="day">29</span>
          <span class="month">Oct</span>
        </div>
        <h4>
          <a href="#">How to make a blog</a>
        </h4>
        <p>
          // content here
       </p>
       <a class="read-more" href="#">
          read more
          <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
       </a>
     </article>
   </div>
   <div class="span3">
      <article>
        <div class="date">
          <span class="day">29</span>
          <span class="month">Oct</span>
        </div>
        <h4>
          <a href="#">How to make a Robot</a>
        </h4>
        <p>
          // content here
       </p>
       <a class="read-more" href="#">
          read more
          <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
       </a>
     </article>
   </div>           
</div>
```

How can I shorten this content and put some dots after.

**JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zKcyC/).**

Comment: Did you mean multi-line `ellipsis`? It didn't work on cross browser,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use some js here

```
$.each($('article p'),function(i,v){
    if($(v).html().length > 100)
        $(v).html( $(v).html().substr(0,200) + "...");        
});
```

check out [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zKcyC/1/)

Comment: It's working. But the blog body will have some other elements also, like ``<li>`` after ``<p>``.Then what can I do? I don't want to show this content also. Check fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/zKcyC/3/

Comment: you can hide that content using selectors, in most case the format of html will be known to you. updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zKcyC/5/

Comment: The article body will be generated using CKEditor, so user can enter any elements not only ``ul``. So I can't write selectors for all elements. Now I am planning to try php ``substr($article->body,0,200).'...';``

Comment: if that works, great..  else you can hide all the children for article intially and then show only a few of them using selectors like the date div , header tag and p tag

Comment: perhaps using classes would help?

Answer (score 1):

for one-line:

```
p {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

for multi-line, webkit browser(including safari, chrome, mobile-safari and etc..):

```
p {
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* line-number */    
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical; 
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a div instead of p tag, p tag will also do, and add a class to it with following CSS

```
.myeclipse{
    white-space:nowrap; 
    width:12em;
    height:8em;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

but as you have br in between, it will apply to all lines individually, to avoid this, remove br

Comment: Issue solved by ``substr($article->body,0,200).'...';``. And this answer also working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675034/shorten-content-of-an-element-using-css/19675126#19675126